# std::thread throws Access violation exception when created with arguments?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I'm using VS2015 and encounter a extremely strange problem when using std::thread.

```
void Klass::myfunc(int a, int b) { std::cout << a << ' ' << b << std::endl; }
// ...
auto t = std::thread(&Klass::myfunc, this, 100, 200); <- runtime error after called
// ...
t.join();
```

It works well on Debug mode, but throws an "Access violation exception" when I turn to Release mode.

What's more, if I try to modify "myfunc" to this:

```
void Klass::myfunc() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
// ...
auto t = std::thread(&Klass::myfunc, this); // everything goes well
// ...
t.join();
```

it works well again.

I'm guarantee that "&Klass::myfunc" and "this" pointers are not NULL. And there is a "join" after several lines when the ctor is called.

I guess it might be some kind of "undefined behavior" but I have no idea what is it exactly.

The call stack is something like this:

```
    000000c83a4ffd40()  Unknown
>   distributed_word_embedding.exe!std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl multiverso::Communicator::*)(void) __ptr64,multiverso::Communicator * __ptr64>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl multiverso::Communicator::*)(void) __ptr64,multiverso::Communicator * __ptr64> > > >::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl multiverso::Communicator::*)(void),multiverso::Communicator *>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl multiverso::Communicator::*)(void),multiverso::Communicator *> > > > * _Ln) Line 247    C++
    distributed_word_embedding.exe!std::_Pad::_Call_func(void * _Data) Line 210 C++
    ucrtbase.dll!00007ffabdc7be1d() Unknown
    kernel32.dll!00007ffabfae8102() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!00007ffac26bc5b4()    Unknown
```

Comment: What happens after you make the thread? Do you `join` it?

Comment: What @doctorlove probably is hinting at is that this looks like a lifetime issue where where the thread outlives the Klass instance and thus has a dangling this-pointer.  By joining at the right place, you can prevent this.  However we can't be sure based on the presented contex.

Comment: @doctorlove stefaanv hi both, thanks for your reply. Actually the debugger and log shows that the program is down right after the ctor of std::thread is called, and the "join" are several lines after. I think the problem is not about "join". And I also mentioned in the question that if I call "myfunc" without arguments, everything goes well.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You should always make sure you join (or possibly detach) a `thread`, otherwise leaving `main` especially with a thread using objects (in this case `this`) will (sometimes) cause problems.

```
//... details omitted...

int main()
{
  auto t = std::thread(&Klass::myfunc, this);
  t.join();  //<----- NOTE THIS
}
```

Anthony William's threading [blog](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-1-starting-threads.html) goes through this in detail. With an example very similar to your second one:

```
void my_thread_func()
{
    std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(my_thread_func);
}
```

He says

> If you compile and run this little application, what happens? Does it
>   print hello like we wanted? Well, actually there's no telling. It
>   might do or it might not. I ran this simple application several times
>   on my machine, and the output was unreliable: sometimes it output
>   "hello", with a newline; sometimes it output "hello" without a
>   newline, and sometimes it didn't output anything. What's up with that?
>   Surely a simple app like this ought to behave predictably?

He then introduces the idea of using `join` as I did above, and says,

> The problem is we're not waiting for our thread to finish. When the
>   execution reaches the end of main() the program is terminated,
>   whatever the other threads are doing.